# Cannot serve video file inline with restricted access?

Tags: video, inline, content-disposition

I am working on a requirement to allow playing .mp4 files from a share point location through links in my application home page. This application is based on forms authentication mode, and I am using a .ashx handler to stream the video by getting the video from the share point location into byte array and writing the response, as below.

```
byte[] response = getfromsharepoint(filepath);
context.Response.BinaryWrite(response);
context.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);
context.Response.AddHeader("content-legth", response.Length.ToString());
context.Response.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-store");
context.Response.End();
```

But, when I attempt it I get this error in Windows Media Player:  "Windows Media Player cannot play the file. The Player might not support the file type or might not support the codec that was used to compress the file."  But when I use "attachment" content-disposition it works fine.

And when I searched on this on web, found a post which suggested to remove the restriction for the handler in the web.config file as below, it worked in inline mode as well, unfortunately, I need to run this in restricted access so that anonymous users will not be able play the video by getting the url.

```
<location path="VideoHandler.ashx"> 
<system.web>
<authorization> 
<allow users="*"/>
</authorization> 
</system.web>

</location>
```

Can someone please suggest a way to achieve this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Media Player doesn't have your auth cookie.

Comment: So, will it not work in restricted mode? can you please suggest?

Comment: Use a signed URL that attackers cannot guess, but will work without cookies.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, but will the user be not able to copy paste this signed url into another session in the browser and try and access the video, anyhow? Can you please give an example, if possible? Currently, url appears like this:http://localhost/Online/Shared/VideoHandler.ashx?Videofile= search&Key=Ins

Comment: There is no way for your server to tell the difference between WMP and a different browser session.  WMP does not have any cookies.

Comment: So is it safe to assume that it will not be nearly as easy to restrict the video from been used by anonymous user unless I use content-disposition "attachment"? Please correct me, if wrong?